# How to create an VPN Client app in flutter or native android or any other framework?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, vpn

I am new to flutter app development , I have knowledge of native android app development. I want to develop an VPN client app for both android and IOS. I did research but did not found any proper information in flutter so switched to android.

For flutter I followed this links:-https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vpn  , https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_openvpn

For native android I followed this link:-
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn

For flutter only found UI part.

Please suggest some references for flutter and native android also

Or Which another framework do I have to use for VPN client app development compatible for android and IOS like single code base framework ? Please suggest their references also.